# Copy Chrome Desktop Settings from One Computer to Another

Tags: linux, chrome-remote-desktop

Is it possible to copy chrome remote desktop settings from one computer to another so that I can access the second computer (while the first one is offline) and vice verse and chrome remote desktop to treat the two machines as one?

Copying the configs directly from `~/.config/chrome-remote desktop`

and
`~/.pki` (if this is also needed)

does not work.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.